how to find explicit formula for A008303?
I tried to find formula for $\Omega_n(a,m)$ for natural $n,a,m$
with $n\ge a , a\ne 0 , n\equiv a \text{ mod2}$  where
$$ \Omega_n(a,m)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^n\left(\tan_mx \right)}{x^a} dx$$
where $\tan_mx=\underbrace{\tan\tan \cdots\tan x}_{\text{$m$ times}} $ with $\tan_0x=x$
and I got recurrence relation for that posted here
for even $n$
$$ \Omega_{2n}(2a,m)=-\frac{1}{(2a-1)!}\sum_{p=1}^a \Omega_{2n}(2p,m-1)\sum_{k=a-p+1}^a \binom{k-1}{a-p}f(2a-1,k)$$
and for odd greater than $1$
$$ \Omega_{2n+1}(2a+1,m)=\frac{1}{(2a)!}\sum_{p=1}^a \Omega_{2n+1}(2p+1,m-1)\sum_{k=a-p+1}^a \binom{k-1}{a-p}f(2a,k)$$
now my question is how to compute $f(a,k)$ which defined by
$$ \frac{d^a}{dx^a} \cot x=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{a+1}{2}\rfloor} f(a,k) (\csc x)^{2k}(\cot x)^{a-2k+1}$$
for example to calculate $f(5,2)$ we need to find coefficient of $(\csc x)^{4}(\cot x)^2$ in the expression
$$ \frac{d^{5}}{dx^{5}} \cot x=-16 (\csc x)^2 (\cot x)^4-88(\csc x)^4 (\cot x)^2-16(\csc x)^6$$
therefore $f(5,2)=-88$
So is there a closed form for computing $f(a,k)$ in simplest way ?
I searched here but I didnt get how to find my coefficients , and I discovered that
$$ f(a,m)=(-1)^{a} A008303(a,m)=(-1)^a 2^{a-k} A094503(a,m)$$
but there is no explicit form for that sequences.
Edition
the answer of the question $n^{th}$ derivative of $\cot x$ give the formula
$$\cot^{(n)}(x)=(-2 i)^n (\cot (x)+i) \underset{k=0}{\overset{n}{\sum }}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k (i \cot (x)+1)^k k! \mathcal{S}_n^{(k)}$$
but it isnt answer my question since I need to put the expression in the form
$$ \frac{d^a}{dx^a} \cot x=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{a+1}{2}\rfloor} f(a,k) (\csc x)^{2k}(\cot x)^{a-2k+1}$$
to find closed form for the $f(a,m)$

I'm not sure how useful it is for your purpose, but $\cot x = i\frac{e^{2ix} + 1}{e^{2ix} - 1}$.

@JeanMarie I put the link of that question and said it didnt answer my question and its compute nth derivative in a different way
